# CentOS 7 and VirtualBox bridged network issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, centos

I have some difficulties getting the network to work on my CentOS 7 VM.

I need to have my adapter on bridged in VirtualBox so I can use the DHCP to obtain an IP address.

[image: VirtualBox network configuration]

The interface is up on CentOS:

[image: result of <code>ip a</code>]

I've enabled the interface with `nmtui`:

[image: nmtui configuration]

Inside the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`, the `ONBOOT` option is set to `YES`

And I don't have any responses when I run a `dhclient -v`.

EDIT : I try to force a static IP and I was able to ping my gateway.
However, I wasn't able to ping something outside my network (ex: google.com) as it's unable to resolve names (I was able to curl the page using the IP and not the host name).

2nd EDIT : The NetwokManager generated a /etc/resolv.conf file with 10.0.2.2 as the DNS IP. I've changed that and I don't have any issues to ping something outside my LAN.

3rd EDIT : I can see that CentOS is asking if there's a DHCP, but get's no response. This might be my router's fault...
[image: wireshark capture]

4th EDIT : Changed LAN and was able to obtain an IP address...

At this point, I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by my home router, wich refused to answer to the DHCP requests of my VM and to provide an IP address.

Don't forget to read all the edits in my question in order to have the full debug process.